# How to run a for loop through two different variable types in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to loop through the axes (0 to 5 & 0 to 1), as well as loop through the columns of my series table (Pandas).

My idea was to do something along the lines of the following:

```
for i in range(3):
        for j in range(2):
            sm.graphics.tsa.plot_acf(series['GBP'], ax[i,j], lags=15, zero=False)
```

However, this prohibits me from looping through the series table. This is how I currently have done this:

```
    sm.graphics.tsa.plot_acf(series['GBP'], ax[0,0], lags=15, zero=False)
    sm.graphics.tsa.plot_acf(series['JPY'], ax[0,1], lags=15, zero=False)
    sm.graphics.tsa.plot_acf(series['DEM'], ax[1,0], lags=15, zero=False)
    sm.graphics.tsa.plot_acf(series['BEF'], ax[1,1], lags=15, zero=False)
    sm.graphics.tsa.plot_acf(series['FRF'], ax[2,0], lags=15, zero=False)
    sm.graphics.tsa.plot_acf(series['ITL'], ax[2,1], lags=15, zero=False)
    sm.graphics.tsa.plot_pacf(series['GBP'], ax[3,0], lags=15, zero=False)
    sm.graphics.tsa.plot_pacf(series['JPY'], ax[3,1], lags=15, zero=False)
    sm.graphics.tsa.plot_pacf(series['DEM'], ax[4,0], lags=15, zero=False)
    sm.graphics.tsa.plot_pacf(series['BEF'], ax[4,1], lags=15, zero=False)
    sm.graphics.tsa.plot_pacf(series['FRF'], ax[5,0], lags=15, zero=False)
    sm.graphics.tsa.plot_pacf(series['ITL'], ax[5,1], lags=15, zero=False)
```

There should be a more efficient way, I just can't get my head around it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `zip` the dataframe's columns and the flattened axis together and then run a loop:

```py
for axis, col in zip(ax.flatten(), series):
    sm.graphics.tsa.plot_pacf(series[col], ax=axis, lags=15, zero=False)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot. Much appreciated!